# Write a Python program using lists, function and loops that will prompt a user to enter a temperature as an integer

Tags: python

Write a Python program using lists, function and loops that will prompt
a user to enter a temperature as an integer. Your program will print "it
is hot" if the temperature is over 100, "it is cold" if the temperature is
under 60, and "it is just right" if the temperature is between 61 and 99
inclusive. The program continues to ask for temperatures, and
evaluates them as above, until the user enters a temperature of 0 (to
exit the program). An example of the anticipated program is shown
below:

```
Please enter a temperature: 95
It is just right.
Please enter a temperature: 110
It is hot.
Please enter a temperature: 32
It is cold.
Please enter a temperature: 0
Good bye!
```

```
temp = int(input("Enter the temperature: ")) 
while temp != 1: 
    if temp >= 100: 
        print ("It is hot") 
    elif temp <= 60:
        print ("It is cold")
    elif temp == 0:
        print ("Good bye")
    else: 
        print ("It is just right")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# firsly define a function

def solve():

    # define a infinite loop
    while True:

        # take int number as input 
        temp = int(input("Enter the temperature: ")) 

        if temp == 0:
            print ("Good bye!")
            # if temperature is zero exit the loop using "break" 
            break

        # write other conditions

        if temp >= 100:
            print ("It is hot.")
        elif temp <= 60:
            print ("It is cold.")
        else :
            print ("It is just right.")

# call the function
solve()
```

Answer (score 0):

Three suggestions:

1. Move the `input` inside the `while` loop so that you will prompt for input on each iteration of the loop.
2. Make the `while` loop on `True` instead of `temp != 1` so that it won't exit prematurely if the user enters `1`.
3. Add a `break` statement to the `temp == 0` block so that the loop will exit at that point.